# FULL OUTER JOIN of two INNER JOINs

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have three tables.
My Table `Order` has an `Id` and a `Date`.
Likewise my table `Delivery` has an `Id` and a `Date`.
My third table `Part` has an `Id`, and two foreign keys to `Order` and `Delivery`: `OrderId`, `DeliveryId`.

I want to create a query that gives me an overview over the count of orders and deliveries per month, like this:

```
+------+-------+------------+---------------+
| Year | Month | OrderCount | DeliveryCount |
+------+-------+------------+---------------+
| 2021 | 2     | 10         | 12            |
+------+-------+------------+---------------+
| 2021 | 1     | 234        | 213           |
+------+-------+------------+---------------+
| ...  | ...   | ...        | ...           |
+------+-------+------------+---------------+
```

So I created a query that gives me the orders per month:

```
SELECT 
  MONTH(o.[Date]) AS [Month],
  YEAR(o.[Date]) AS [YEAR],
  COUNT(p.Id) AS OrderCount
FROM           
  Part AS p
INNER JOIN
  [Order] AS o ON o.Id = p.OrderId
GROUP BY 
  MONTH(o.[Date]), YEAR(o.[Date])
```

and one for the deliveries per month:

```
SELECT 
  MONTH(d.[Date]) AS [Month],
  YEAR(d.[Date]) AS [YEAR],
  COUNT(p.Id) AS DeliveryCount
FROM           
  Part AS p
INNER JOIN
  Delivery AS d ON d.Id = p.DeliveryId
GROUP BY 
  MONTH(d.[Date]), YEAR(d.[Date])
```

But now I am struggling with joining them. I think I need a `FULL OUTER JOIN`, because I need the Month/Year/DeliveryCount when there is no order but deliveries and vice versa.

What I have tried is

```
SELECT 
  MONTH(o.Date) AS [Month]
  YEAR(o.Date) as [Year]
  COUNT(p.Id) as OrderCount
FROM           
  Part AS p
INNER JOIN
  [Order] AS o ON o.Id = p.OrderId
GROUP BY 
MONTH(o.Date), Year(o.Date)

FULL OUTER JOIN

(SELECT 
  MONTH(d.Date) AS [Month]
  YEAR(d.Date) as [Year]
  COUNT(pp.Id) as DeliveryCount
FROM           
  Part AS pp
INNER JOIN
  Delivery AS d ON d.Id = pp.DeliveryId
GROUP BY 
MONTH(d.Date), YEAR(d.Date)) AS d ON d.[Month] = MONTH(o.Date) AND d.[Year] = YEAR(o.Date)
```

But that's not how `FULL OUTER JOINS` work.

How do I get a full outer of these two inner joins?
Or is this approach of outer joining two inner joins wrong in the first place?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  A SQL/DB fiddle of some sort would be a big bonus.  I'm also lost on what the "part" table has to do with *orders per month*.

Comment: You have a number of issues. First off, how do your individual queries run with no commas between the columns?

Whenever I am building a more complex query I always make sure the smaller queries work and return the data I am expecting first.

Your issue is that you are treating Orders and Deliveries differently. You need to alias you Orders query just like you are with you Deliveries query.

Comment: Sorry, I on the fly translated my real code into something not as specific, more generic and easier to understand. I accidentally made some mistakes like the missing commas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to treat your two queries as sub-queries.
This should give you the desired result

```
 Select Orders.OrderCount, Deliveries.DeliveryCount
    from (
    SELECT 
      MONTH(o.Date) AS [Month]
      YEAR(o.Date) AS [YEAR]
      COUNT(p.Id) AS OrderCount
    FROM           
      Part AS p
    INNER JOIN
      [Order] AS o ON o.Id = p.OrderId
    GROUP BY 
      MONTH(o.Date), YEAR(o.Date)
    ) Orders

 

    FULL OUTER JOIN
    
    (
    SELECT 
      MONTH(d.Date) AS [Month]
      YEAR(d.Date) AS [YEAR]
      COUNT(p.Id) AS DeliveryCount
    FROM           
      Part AS p
    INNER JOIN
      Delivery AS d ON d.Id = p.DeliveryId
    GROUP BY 
      MONTH(d.Date), YEAR(d.Date) ) Deliveries
    

    on Orders.Month = Deliveries.Month
        and Orders.Year = Deliveries.Year
```

Comment: @herrwolken Notice how the formatting of the code makes reading it and understanding it easier. That is a good habit to develop.

Comment: @SMor, yes I will try to improve (further). Still working on the BEST way to do that.

Comment: Most programming languages have ONE (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/,  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions, https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html )  style guide while for SQL I found multiple ones that have different ideas on how to format the commands.

Answer (score 1):

This would solve your problem.
In case you have months/year missing, use other join.

```
WITH OrdersMonth AS (
SELECT 
  MONTH(o.Date) AS [Month]
  YEAR(o.Date) AS [YEAR]
  COUNT(p.Id) AS OrderCount
FROM           
  Part AS p
INNER JOIN
  [Order] AS o ON o.Id = p.OrderId
GROUP BY 
  MONTH(o.Date), YEAR(o.Date)
), DeliveriesMonth AS (
SELECT 
  MONTH(d.Date) AS [Month]
  YEAR(d.Date) AS [YEAR]
  COUNT(p.Id) AS DeliveryCount
FROM           
  Part AS p
INNER JOIN
  Delivery AS d ON d.Id = p.DeliveryId
GROUP BY 
  MONTH(d.Date), YEAR(d.Date)
)

SELECT om.YEAR
      ,om.Month
      ,om.OrderCount
      ,dm.DeliveryCount
 FROM OrdersMonth om
      LEFT JOIN DeliveriesMonth dm ON om.om.YEAR = dm.YEAR AND om.Month = dm.Month
```